# Apache module supports in wsman profile

Tags: apache, tomcat, wsman

I want to know which all modules in apache server supports wsman profile completly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have mod_wsman module for configuring openwsman web service in apache.
You can download source code from this link .https://github.com/Openwsman/mod_wsman 
make , install and configure it in apache.

mod_wsman is openwsman-server but without the http stack.

It's an Apache plugin, so you can use the Apache http stack to handle 
requests and pass them to the openwsman-server backend for processing.

mod_wsman is not very well maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by wsman you mean WS-Management...

Of the standard modules that ship with Apache Web Server (httpd). None.

Apache Tomcat also has no support for this.